# Scroll Multiple CollectionViews simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a tableView with 20 tableViewCells and within each cell I insert a collectionView (with 100 cells) which scrolls horizontally. I would like to scroll ALL collectionViews when any of the collectionViews is scrolled.

### Implementation

I have subclassed the collectionView and have overridden scrollView delegates.

I have currently gotten this to work with the following approaches:

1. When ANY CollectionView is scrolled, I get all visible tableViewCells and grab the collectionsViews within each cell and set the collectionView contentOffsets iteratively or by using makeObjectsPerformSelector.
2. Had a CGPoint property with an observer which triggers when the property changes; then inside the collectionView subclass scrollViewDidScroll: I set the property, this will trigger the observer and set the collectionView accordingly. (the collectionView contentOffset is set inside observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:)
3. I have also used NSNotificationCenter to broadcast any scroll and in-turn scroll every other listener

The problem I face is that the collectionViews scrolls are a bit glitch sometimes especially when the scroll is coming to a halt. currently there is no data in collectionView cells but it glitches.

Please does anyone know of a way to simultaneously scroll multiple collectionViews without glitches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single UICollectionView is perfectly capable of handling 20 rows of 100 items as described. Why would you want to use multiple collection views in a table view for that?

Comment: If you want to make a grid then it's better to use a collection view with custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass, you will get better performance and no glitches.

Comment: @Rein My design is a collabsible grid so this so far seems to the suitable design

Comment: @Oleg I am using a custom flow layout however I still have glitches, I have a static cell in the collectionview so I constantly have to call prepareForLayout